# Add a color overlay on hover

Tags: html, css, svg, onhover

I want to achieve this functionality as shown in image.[image]

Image on left is orignal and when I hover over that image, Some color defined by us should overlay image as shown in Right. I have tried using CSS no use. I was trying to achieve this thru SVGs, but I am not much experienced in it. Is there any method which can be used to achieve this effect.

**UPDATE**

- I don't want to use any extra image on hover.
- I may be able to select any other color instead of black on hover.

Comment: Why not, use images - on hover ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. No use of Images on hover...

Comment: You can easily do this using svg. But you need to have the image as svg file

Comment: Images are in raster format, jpg or png. Can we Include it and anyhow edit that SVG. Is it possible?

Comment: I have done with svg, I am not sure if you can do with png, jpg. If you have an svg and post it in the question, I cans how you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with `webkit-filter`.

Please try for not hovered image:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: contrast(10) grayscale(1);
}
```

And then drop all filters on hovered:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

What you have to know, NOT ALL browsers supports `-webkit-filter`. Also its nice idea to check [this page](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html). It will help you with finding correct values.

Comment: I want to be able to replace that overlay with any color.

Comment: well, I learned a bit about CSS filters.. but not exactly what I needed here in this question.

Comment: Thats only one thing i know you can do if you dont want to use second image.

Answer (score 0):

use can use two Images on hover u can show second image and hide first image.similarly u can do this with second image

Comment: I don't want to use 2nd Image. Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

propose here is a solution using sprites  [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fwGde)

```
<div class="picture-hover"></div>

.picture-hover {
            background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/55veX.png);
            width: 239px;
            height: 180px;
        }
        .picture-hover:hover {
            background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/55veX.png);
            width: 239px;
            height: 180px;
            background-position: -239px 0px;
        }
```

Comment: I want to be able to overlay multiple colors as per users choice.

Comment: You can use webkit-filter: opacity (25%); but this method is not browser-based crossover

Comment: That doesnot give output as desired.

Comment: You can use svg, image transfer to svg file type font, connect through font-face and use psevdo element hover with the desired color to fill